# SetTimeout multithreading in Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, multithreading, titanium

So I'm making a titanium application and I've found that on Android the single thread is being overloaded, causing large lock-ups. My boss is insisting that using setTimeout can be used to mimic multithreading and reduce the lag. I however have read that this is not the case as javascript cannot multithread, nor "fake it". Could someone please explain in clear terms whether or not I can utilize in setTimeout in this manner (I need to be able to bring this to my boss)

Comment: Please provide a bit more detail about what is it that you are trying to accomplish by using "multithreading"?

Comment: Prevent the main thread from becoming overwhelmed. By distributing the loading across multiple threads to allow the app to load within a second or two instead of the multiple seconds it's taking. The issue is really that Titanium is not very well optimized for android. So loading content that SHOULD be seamless is taking several seconds.

Comment: By loading the app you mean an app start or loading some content from an http call?

Comment: Ultimately there is no way to do multithreading in JS, and yes you can use setTimeout to set different times of execution for functions. If you are loading content based on an http call response, these are asynchronous, you don't need a setTimeout, just execute your functions or UI update in the callback of the http call.